# What's wrong with this command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I entered this and it says this all the time

> Data Tag Parsing Failed: Encountered Multiple Top Tags, Only One Expected

And here is the command:

```
/summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {NoAI:1,Rotation:[45.0f,-15.0f]},{CustomName:"Fire"}
```

Comment: For reference, one should [avoid using capital letters for the beginning of *every single* word](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/capital.asp).

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to separate the `{NoAI:1,Rotation:[45.0f,-15.0f]}` portion of the NBT tag and the `{CustomName:"Fire"}` portion. In fact, it's causing the syntax error here.

What you're going to want is as follows:

```
/summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {NoAI:1,Rotation:[45.0f,-15.0f],CustomName:"Fire"}
```

Additionally, you may want to add `CustomNameVisible:1` to the NBT tag to make the name show up like a player name, so the command becomes the following:

```
/summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {NoAI:1,Rotation:[45.0f,-15.0f],CustomName:"Fire",CustomNameVisible:1}
```

Comment: After testing, I'm not quite clear what `CustomNameVisible` does. I'll do some more science to find out.

Comment: it forces a custom name to be visible/invisible, if you set it to`0` you won't see the name, useful for crazy commandblock stuff and custom maps. also sorry for necropost